# Local normal domains

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $(A,\mathfrak{m}_A)\subseteq(B,\mathfrak{m}_B)$ two local Noetherian domain such that $\mathfrak{m}_B=\mathfrak{m}_AB$ . Is it true that if $A$ is normal then also $B$ is normal?

Notice that the claim is of course true if we assume that $A$ is regular.

Comment: Please avoid posting question statements without your own context, and please avoid phrasing things as "yes/no" or "true/false" questions. Perhaps you could tell us a bit about how you arrived at the question.